# Why scutil always try to modify system network configuration

Tags: macos, network, proxy

I set a global sockets proxy via 'Settings'-'Network'.

Then **scutil** always tries to revert my setting, then prompt a dialog to ask my password to allow this change. I can cancel it, but it will be popped up in few seconds.

Does anybody know why **scutil** wants to do it? And how to forbid this change forever?

Comment: The tool `scutil` is like the [scorpion in this tale](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Scorpion_and_the_Frog) - it's job is to mess with settings when asked. Deleting the tool would be foolhardy, so you will need to track down why it is being called. Search the forums here about `fs_usage` and ask if you can't figure out how to use it to narrow down when the tool runs. You may not have provided enough detail for anyone to guess an answer directly.

Comment: @bmike, looks like fs_usage does not help.


`localhost% sudo fs_usage scutil                 

18:23:58  fstat64  0.000004   scutil  

18:23:58  write    0.000006   scutil  

18:23:58  read     0.000003   scutil  

18:24:07  write    0.000007 scutil  
                       
18:24:07  close    0.000007   scutil`

Comment: Well - then you'll have to either wait for someone to know exactly what you are seeing or perhaps show more of your work in the question. It could be a managed lab environment where the admin doesn't want you changing things, where you are not an admin, where other software is running, or a whole host of other things. Basically - if no one has an answer, you might have to explain how you are seeing `scutil` change things and set up this problem in more detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it's a bug of Lion Mountain, and it has been fixed by Apple.

The dialog won't appear after updating to 10.8.2.